# Python XML comparison is failing due to extra element tag in one of the XMLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have a script which is comparing two XMLs. Comparison is working fine if all the element tags are the same under `<account>` tag but after adding an extra tag `<branchID5>` in `b.xml` for account# `600789488` then it is not printing the differences.

```
a.xml

<svc>
  <accounts>
    <account>
      <acctBasicInfo>
        <acctName>600789488</acctName>
        <branchID2>56</branchID2>
        <realparties>
          <realparty>
            <realname>lui</realname>
          </realparty> 
        </realparties>   
      </acctBasicInfo>  
    </account>
    <account>
      <acctBasicInfo>
        <acctName>44646</acctName>
        <branchID2>86</branchID2>
        <realparties>
          <realparty>
            <realname>lui</realname>
          </realparty> 
        </realparties>   
      </acctBasicInfo>  
    </account>
  </accounts>
</svc>
```

```
b.xml

<svc>
  <accounts>
    <account>
      <acctBasicInfo>
        <acctName>44646</acctName>
        <branchID2>86</branchID2>
        <realparties>
          <realparty>
            <realname>lui</realname>
          </realparty> 
        </realparties>   
      </acctBasicInfo>  
    </account>
    <account>
      <acctBasicInfo>
        <acctName>600789488</acctName>
        <branchID2>56</branchID2>
        <branchID5>66</branchID5>
        <realparties>
          <realparty>
            <realname>lu</realname>
          </realparty> 
        </realparties>   
      </acctBasicInfo>  
    </account>
  </accounts>
</svc>
```

code:

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict
from pprintpp import pprint as pp

root_1 = etree.parse('a.xml').getroot()
root_2 = etree.parse('b.xml').getroot()

d1, d2 = [], []
for node in root_1.findall('.//account'):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
      for k, v in x.attrib.items():
          item[k].append(v)
      if x.text is None:
        item[x.tag].append('None')
      elif x.text.strip():
        item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
    d1.append(dict(item))



for node in root_2.findall('.//account'):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
      for k, v in x.attrib.items():
          item[k].append(v)
      if x.text is None:
        item[x.tag].append('None')
      elif x.text.strip():
        item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
    d2.append(dict(item))

d1 = sorted(d1, key = lambda x: x['acctName'])
d2 = sorted(d2, key = lambda x: x['acctName'])
print(d1)
print(d2)


res_dict = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in zip(d1, d2):
  for key1, key2 in zip(x.keys(), y.keys()):
      if (key1 == key2) and sorted(x[key1]) != sorted(y[key2]):
        a =set(x[key1])
        b = set(y[key2])
        diff = ([(i+'--'+'test1.xml') if i in a else (i+'--'+'test2.xml') if i in b else '' for i in list(a^b)])
        res_dict[x['acctName'][0]].append({key1: diff})

if res_dict == {}:
  print('Data is same in both XML files')
else:
  pp(dict(res_dict))
```

Current output: It is not finding the differences. because `branchID5': ['66']` is coming before different `realname': ['lu']` in d2

```
d1:
[{'acctName': ['44646'], 'branchID2': ['86'], 'realname': ['lui']}, {'acctName': ['600789488'], 'branchID2': ['56'], 'realname': ['lui']}]
d2:
[{'acctName': ['44646'], 'branchID2': ['86'], 'realname': ['lui']}, {'acctName': ['600789488'], 'branchID2': ['56'], 'branchID5': ['66'], 'realname': ['lu']}]
Data is same in both XML files
```

Expected output: It should print the differences. It should ignore the uncommon element tags from both the xmls

```
{'600789488': [{'realname': ['lui--test1.xml', 'lu--test2.xml']}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you made it a little more complicated than absolutely necessary. Since you are using etree, you might as well use xpath to get there.

```
names1 = root1.xpath('.//account/acctBasicInfo')

for name in names1:
    rn = name.xpath('.//realname/text()')[0] #get the real name in root1
    actNm = name.xpath('./acctName/text()')[0] #get the acctName in root1
    #next line is the key: create a search expression to find in root2 an account with the same acctName as in the current node of root1
    exp = f'.//account/acctBasicInfo[acctName/text()={actNm}]//realname/text()'    
    twin = root2.xpath(exp)[0] #execute the search
    #now compare the real names in both accounts in the two roots, and if not the same, create alert
    if rn != twin:
        print({f'{actNm}': [{'realname': [f'{rn}--test1.xml', f'{twin}--test2.xml']}]})
```

Output:

```
{'600789488': [{'realname': ['lui--test1.xml', 'lu--test2.xml']}]}
```

Comment: It is working but this is more like specific for this example. Code i have put in question is for General tags. Like there are 100s of tags and any tag can be extra in any of the xml

Comment: @AbhinandanMehandiratta I'm not sure what you mean. Generally speaking, people here can only respond to what is in your question. So if your question doesn't really represent your problem, edit your question until it does.

Comment: Sure i will do that